# Соединение с MySQL: Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource

Tags: mysql

Скажите что не так,

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', '123456') || die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('test', $db) || die(mysql_error());
mysql_set_charset('SET NAMES UTF-8');
?>
```

при открытии connect.php написано:

> Warning: mysql_select_db() expects parameter 2 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\home\localhost\www\content\connect.php on line 4

Comment: Подключение что-то не срабатывает... Вы точно указали правильные логин и пароль?

Comment: правильно, но попробую нового пользователя сделать

Comment: изменил пользователя, толку нет, все та же ошибка!

Comment: А если так `mysql_select_db('test')`?

Comment: Это у Вас результат операции `||`. Попробуйте разнести

      $db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', '123456');
      $db || die(mysql_error());

или

      ($db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'admin', '123456')) || die(mysql_error());

Comment: попробовал через php создать создать базу и таблицу. Правильный ли код header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sew810i9', '1234') or die ('Нет соединения');
$base = "CREATE DATABASE mydb" or die ("База не создана");
$table = "CREATE TABLE mytable (title TEXT)";
mysql_select_db($table, $db);

не база не таблица не создались!

Comment: Попробуйте через консоль `mysql`. Да и вообще не стоит чистый `mysql` в `php` уже использовать, юзайте `PDO` || `MySQLi`.

Comment: попробовал создать базу и таблицу через php, ничего не получило но и ошибок нету, правильный ли код http://ideone.com/y3WzJW

Comment: @sew810i9 неправильный.

Comment: @sew810i9 На мой комментарий Вы внимания принципиально не обращаете? Ну успеха. Тогда выкиньте свою переменную $db, как это сделал @Maris (для случая одного соединения это должно работать)

Answer (score 1):

```
header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf8');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'sew810i9', '1234') or die ('Нет соединения');
mysql_select_db('test');
$sql = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS mydb";
if (!$query1 = mysql_query($sql)) die("База не создана ". mysql_error());
$table = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS mytable (id int(11), title varchar(255), PRIMARY KEY(`id`))";
if (!$query2 = mysql_query($table)) die("Таблица не создана ". mysql_error());

if ($query1 and $query2) {
    echo "Создана БД mydb и таблица mytable";
}
```

Вот примерно так если через `php`.

Comment: Ну если не использовать переменную $link, то да. Только вот нафига Вы ей присваиваете значение?